# How to make array of pointers in a struct point to members of same struct

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, struct

I have a struct that looks like this:

```
struct a
{
    std::string timestamp;
    std::string * ptr[1] = {&timestamp};
}
```

I push this struct to a vector and want to make the pointer in the array point to the timestamp variable of that same struct within the vector.

Elsewhere, I have pointer `std::string **y` which points to the array pointer using the following:

```
y = &mQueue[x].ptr[0];
```

I then set the value of `y` using data from a local array like this:

```
**y = data[0];
```

Now, when I output the value of `**y` and `*mQueue[x].ptr[0]`, they both have the same value, which they should, but when I output the value of mQueue[x].timestamp, which is what I expected both pointers to ultimately be pointing to, it is blank, and I can't seem to figure out why the array pointer isn't pointing to the struct variable, or where they are actually pointing to if not that variable.

Anyone know where I'm going wrong and how to fix it?

Comment: It works on my machine.  A [mcve] would be very, very helpful.  I probably didn't put in the bug in my code.

Comment: `a` needs a copy constructor, and likely an assignment operator. The implicitly-defined one doesn't do the right thing (it makes `left_hand_side.ptr` point to `right_hand_side.timestamp`). Those pointers likely become dangling shortly thereafter. Why do you feel the need to have pointers to the struct's own members in the first place?

Comment: @IgorTandetnik A pointer array seemed to be the easiest way for me to be able to loop through struct members, rather than having to write out the long list of members every time.

Comment: Why not have an array of strings to begin with, rather than spelling out individual string members and then also maintaining pointers to them?

Comment: @Eljay hmm... I'll set up an example shortly.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik because there are times where I want to be able to refer to individual members, and it's easier to do so by name than number, especially since this program will be updated in the future and i'll need to add more members in different positions, so I'd rather just have both options available to me from the start and use whichever one is easier at any given point in the code.

Comment: Provide accessor functions, as in `string& someName() { return my_array[42]; }`